# PHP and scientific notation, getting different results on same server

Tags: php, codeigniter, number-formatting

I'm using an API to sync reports from a remote service, the id's of records I get are supposed to be formatted like so: 2090708834850341888.
I've setup a testing environment on the same server as my production environmnet under dev.mydomain.com and run the sync process.

on the testing application I get the id formatted correctly: 2090708834850341888
while on the production application the id end up like this: 2.0907088348503E+18

both environments are on the same server, same code, same php version. also the application is using codeigniter.
any clue?

Comment: `precision` value in `php.ini`?

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks that worked, although I've checked "percision" value with ini_get on both environments and both returned 14 (?)